# Sublimetext3, Find... dialog, shortcut for Find and select all matches

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to quickly select certain lines to apply multiple cursor edits on them.

This process should be superfast and using **only keyboard**.

1. <kbd>Ctrl></kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> Open *Find...* dialog
2. `^C` regex to match
3. <kbd>??</kbd> <- *Find all and Select all* command
4. profit

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> selects all occurences of highlighted text when in editor, but does not work in *Find...* dialog.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt+Enter should do the trick.  (the shortcut can be confirmed by moving your mouse onto the `Find All` button in the find panel.

Tip: if you turn on `Highlight matches` in the find panel, you should see real time matches in your file.  This helps you to be sure what are selected when you press Alt+Enter.

If you turn on command logging (Ctrl+`, then enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`), you should see that

```
command: find_all {"close_panel": true}
```

is issued when you perform the operations above.